# laravel eloquent orm insert query auto generated created at and updated at are not coherent with the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Lumen 5.2 to access MySql.
After listen the query and log the sql, I see

```
[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Events\\QueryExecuted: {\"sql\":\"insert into
`RedEnvelopes` (`User_id`, `amount`, `remain`, `expiredAt`, `to_User_id`,        
`message`, `type`, `dividend`, `updatedAt`, `createdAt`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)\",\"bindings\":
[5000219,\"1\",\"1\",1478073412,\"8000228\",\"你的名字\",1,1,\"2016-11-02 
15:51:52\",\"2016-11-02 15:51:52\"],\"time\":0.77,\"connection\":
{},\"connectionName\":\"mysql\"})
```

And using Model::find() to get the record, the return is coherent with the sql above. But when I access MySql server directly and get the record by SQL, the createdAt and updatedAt are later than the the binding values by 8 hours.

I'm totally confused. Anyone else have encountered this question? I need some help.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql Your local time is probably different from mysql timezone

Comment: 8 hours exactly ? Sounds like a timezone problem to me..

Comment: you're using vagrant?

Comment: I believe laravel stores dates in UTC. When retrieving it, sets it back to the system timezone unless you specify a timezone. EDIT: tried to confirm this but don't really have time to go through the [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Comment: Is you're Laravel applications timezone set to the correct one?

Comment: @Ours I guess so, but the sql is the point.

Comment: so which one is the correct date the mysql or the laravel?

Comment: @NewbeeDev No, I'm using Centos.

Comment: @NewbeeDev laravel is correct.

Comment: @Mihai mysql> select now(); +---------------------+ | now() | +---------------------+ | 2016-11-02 16:21:12 | +---------------------+ 1 row in set (0.01 sec) I think Mysql timezone is the same as my local timezone.

Comment: how about changing your centos timezone

Comment: @LaurentMeganck I overwrite the freshTimestamp method
    {    return new Carbon(null, config('app.timezone')); } The app.timezone is set to my local timezone.

Comment: More information. I run the laravel query sql on mysql client, the inserted row is correct.

Comment: @RossWilson yes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be resolved by 3 steps.

First, set the timezone to your local timezone. Mine is Asia/Shanghai. See .env

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Shanghai
```

Second, set app timezone in config/app.php

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE'),
```

Last, change created_at/updated_at column to datetime type.